# Restrict the word "why" in questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, closed-questions

There's way too many nonsense questions being asked, all starting with the word "why".

It devalues the site greatly, making it appear more like a gathering of conspiracy theorists and other crackpots.

Sadly many of them will upvote each others' questions, so they don't get to a close treshold.

<>

Comment: closing _always_ requires 5 community (or one ♦) votes, the threshold set by votes you probably mean is for _deletion_ which should not be used for simply off-topic questions.

Comment: Apart from that, the usage of a question word like "why" is not an indicator for question quality

Answer (score 13):

If you believe the questions are nonsense:

- downvote them
- flag them for moderator attention

Make use of the tools  you have!

Answer (score 8):

You are upset about bad questions, not about using the word "why".

Just because many bad questions use the word "why" doesn't mean that questions using the word "why" will be bad.

Comment: did write it was tongue in cheek, but apparently that didn't make it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no official restrictions put on "Conspiracy theorists" or a strict margin on when a question becomes "Stupid", we could safely assume that questions are judged and authorized currently in an affable way.
Besides that, the question word **why** is not the only type that might lead to a purposeless question:

1. How're people ok with this?
2. Don't you guys think this is stupid?
3. What were they thinking?
4. When will NASA start listening to me?

OK, you get the point.
 In my opinion, Just doing all those things we could with those tools provided to us, in the absence of which moderators could be notified, would ensure a genuine silly-question could be taken care of.

Comment: Oh, and "Who is the president of Physics?" (Taken from an XKCD comic, a very common thing some crackpots like to say.) : )